# how to check the model using mvvm in swift3

Tags: swift

```
how to init the model
```

my model:-

```
class CartModel: NSObject {

    var restaurantname :String!

    init?(dictionary :JSONDictionary) {

        guard let name = dictionary["name"] as? String  else {
            return
        }

        self.restaurantname = name

    }

}
```

my viewmodel:-

```
class ChartViewModel: NSObject {


    var datasourceModel:ChartDataSourceModel

    init(withdatasource  newDatasourceModel: ChartDataSourceModel) {
        datasourceModel = newDatasourceModel
    }


    func datafordisplay(atindex indexPath: IndexPath) -> M_CartModel{
        return  datasourceModel.dataListArray![indexPath.row]

    }

    func numberOfRowsInSection(section:Int) -> Int {

        return (datasourceModel.dataListArray?.count)!
    }




}
```

my datasourcemodel:-

```
class ChartDataSourceModel: NSObject {
    var dataListArray:Array<CartModel>? = []


    init(array :Array<[String:Any]>?) {
        super.init()
        var newArray:Array<[String:Any]> = []
        if array == nil{

            newArray = self.getJsonDataStored22()
        }
        else{
            newArray = array!

        }

        var datalist:Array<CartModel> = []
        for dict in newArray{

            let model = CartModel(dictionary: dict)

            datalist.append(model!)
        }
        self.dataListArray = datalist
    }



}

typealias dummyDataSource22 =  ChartDataSourceModel
extension dummyDataSource22{

    func getJsonDataStored22() ->Array<Dictionary<String,String>>{

        let jsonArray = [["name":"Dosa Fest"],["name":"Organic Vegan Fest"],["name":"Food Of Life Time"],["name":"Tea Time","imageurl":"","location":"Doha,Qatar","date":"Jan 2018","place":"Doha Food Mall"],["name":"Dosa Fest"],["name":"Organic Vegan Fest"],["name":"Food Of Life Time"],["name":"Tea Time"]] as Array<Dictionary<String,String>>

        return jsonArray
    }




my viewcontroller:-

class ChartViewController: UIViewController ,UITableViewDataSource,UITabBarDelegate{

    @IBOutlet private weak var tableView: UITableView!

    private var chartViewModel :ChartViewModel!

    init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?, withViewModel viewModel:ChartViewModel) {

        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)

        chartViewModel = viewModel
    }



    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.93, green: 0.86, blue: 1, alpha:1.0)


        tableView.dataSource = self



        self.tableView .reloadData()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }




    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return chartViewModel.numberOfRowsInSection(section: section)
    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let identifier = "cell"
        var cell: ChartCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? ChartCell

        if cell == nil {
            tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "ChartCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? ChartCell
        }

        cell.setEventData(charts: chartViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath))


               return cell
    }


}








}
```

in this viewcontroller i have used add button.So while clicking the add button it should list the name on the otherscreen.
So how to do ..

my newmodel:-

```
class newModel: NSObject {
//here how to init the cartmodel......
}
```

How to display the name in newview.
how to do.i need to check whether this model is there.I need to set as optional.

Comment: how to solve the problem

Comment: This isn't difficult, just pass it a dictionary? what code do you have already? no point showing here i need to init model with no code, what is here?

Comment: @Scriptable i need to init the model in othermodel ,how to do

Comment: What is JSONDictionary?

Comment: here i need to check whether the cartModel is init.I need to set as optional

Comment: @Scriptable JSONdICTIONARY IsArray<[String:Any]>?

Comment: @Scriptable IN CartViewcontroller i have to do add .So when add button clicked the name should display in the otherviewcontroller.So how to do

Comment: i dont know. i cannot see your code

Comment: @Scriptable i have updated my code .please check and how to solve.

Comment: what has newModel got to do with it? what data you want to init it with? This question is far too vague for us to help you properly.

Comment: @Scriptable I need to init the cartmodel.i need to check it cartmodel data

Comment: I have shown you how to init the cartmodel and check it in my answer already

Answer (score 0):

```
    let jsonArray = [["name":"Dosa Fest"],["name":"Organic Vegan Fest"],["name":"Food Of Life Time"],["name":"Tea Time","imageurl":"","location":"Doha,Qatar","date":"Jan 2018","place":"Doha Food Mall"],["name":"Dosa Fest"],["name":"Organic Vegan Fest"],["name":"Food Of Life Time"],["name":"Tea Time"]] as Array<Dictionary<String,String>>

class CartModel: NSObject {

    var restaurantname :String!

    init?(dictionary :Dictionary<String,String>) {
        self.restaurantname = dictionary["name"] ?? ""

    }

}
var arrayModel : [CartModel] {

    var models : [CartModel] = []

    for json in jsonArray {
        let model = CartModel(dictionary: json)!
        models.append(model)
    }
    return models
}
```

Comment: i have updated my code.please check..and how to solve the problem

Comment: init?(dictionary :Dictionary<String,String) {
        self.restaurantname = dictionary["name"] ?? "" 
    }...

Comment: how to give add action in cartviewcontroller

Comment: HOW TO SOLVE THE PROBLEM

Comment: hi ,as i told while clicking add button action the name in the cart  should pass to the displayviewcontroller.Same way,i have 3 places where add action take place.1.CartViewcontroller,2.Hotelviewcontroller,3.offerviewcontroller. IN this screen i have add button action.So while clicking add button from this 3 viewcontroller the data from pass to displayviewcontroller.For that ,in displaymodel i need to init this 3 model-cartmodel,hotelmodel,and offermodel.And i need to set as optional .so this is logic ,how to implement

Answer (score 0):

Your answer depends on what JSONDictionary is, where you are getting it from and the scope that you require for your model but the basics are

```
let dict: [JSONDictionary] = [[
     "name": "robbie"
]]

let viewModel = CartModel(dictionary: dict)
```

For a [failable initialiser](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=17) you should check the value and if it is not correct then return nil

```
init?(dictionary :JSONDictionary) {
    guard let name = dictionary["name"] as? String else {
        return nil
    }
    self.restaurantname = name

}
```

with this one you can use:

```
if let model = CartModel(dictionary: dict) { // is optional
    // success
}
```

Comment: according ti this i  not got the answer

Comment: then you should make your question clear. that is how to init your model and that is using an optional init and shown you how to check if init works.